# Truncate MySQL table via PHP Function not working

Tags: php, mysql, truncate

I've been looking around and have found others with similar problems, but in most cases they've just not used the 'global' keyword before calling their DB connection. Basically, I'm trying to run a function that truncates a table based on what is passed in the function.

In recipes.php

```
 truncate_table('bl_recipes');
```

And in functions.php

```
 // Truncate table passed in function
function truncate_table($table) {
global $con;
$truncate_query = '"TRUNCATE TABLE  ' . $table . '"';
$truncate = mysqli_query($con, $truncate_query);
if ($truncate) {
echo 'Table truncated.';
}
else {
echo 'Table not truncated.';
echo 'The query was ' . $truncate_query;
}
}
```

If I echo $truncate I get TRUNCATE TABLE 'bl_recipes'; which is exactly what I get if I truncate manually from PHPMyAdmin. Details in $con are correct as other queries work, although none of them have been from within the functions.php file. The database connection itself is defined in functions.php currently, which I may move later but for now during development I'm not fussed where it is. User has all db privileges. Result on page load is "Table not truncated".

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?
Cheers,
Lee.

Comment: how about checking for errors

Comment: $truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE $table"; try this one instead of $truncate_query = '"TRUNCATE TABLE  ' . $table . '"';

Comment: `$truncate_query = '"TRUNCATE TABLE  ' . $table . '"';` is wrong. You should write like this `$truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE ` " . $table . "`";`

Comment: check the error first echo mysqli_error()

Comment: Ah, silly me, I was under the impression there was no errors because I had the PHP errors set to E_ALL. I'll be sure to remember the MySQL errors are separate from now on!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
$truncate_query = 'TRUNCATE TABLE  `' . $table .'`';
```

or this

```
$truncate_query = "TRUNCATE TABLE  `$table`";
```

Comment: Wow. That was surprisingly simple. I can't believe that's all it was. I was mislead by the fact that no errors were produced, and that when echoed it appeared correct. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: @LeeValentine, glab to be of help but please note that the echo you printed is not correct. `TRUNCATE TABLE 'bl_recipes';` should have backtick marks instead of single quotes around the table name

Comment: OH! Thank you again! I hadn't even noticed that!